# How does JS filter the contents of an array without confusion

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the content of 'phone'

I have the following code:

```js
var testList = [{
content:[
    {id:1,uId:1,text:"apple", category: "phone"},
    {id:2,uId:2,text:"nick",category: "life"},
    {id:3,uId:3,text:"samsung",category: "phone"}],
user:[
 {id:1,name: "Joe"},
 {id:2,name: "red"},
 {id:3,name: "blue"}
  ]
}]

const newArrys = testList
  .filter((element) =>
    element.content.some((subElement) => subElement.category == "phone"))
  .map(element => {
    return Object.assign({}, element, {
      content: element.content.filter(subElement => subElement.category == "phone")
    });
  });
console.log(newArrys);
```

These are the returns：

```
[{
content:[
    {id:1,uId:1,text:"apple", category: "phone"},
    {id:3,uId:3,text:"samsung",category: "phone"}],
user:[
 {id:1,name: "Joe"},
 {id:2,name: "red"},
 {id:3,name: "blue"}
  ]
}]
```

I want the result:

```
[{
content:[
    {id:1,uId:1,text:"apple", category: "phone"},
    {id:3,uId:3,text:"samsung",category: "phone"}],
user:[
 {id:1,name: "Joe"},
 {id:3,name: "blue"}
  ]
}]
```

How should I filter 'user'? , and correspond to 'content'

Can you help me? thank you

Comment: You must filter the User with the same content Id.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira What should I do?Can you help me?

Comment: do the user indieces follow the content indices? or is `id` the common part?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes,Follow content index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a `Set` of `id's` that are having category as phone and then filter values based on the Set

```js
var testList = [{content:[{id:1,uId:1,text:"apple", category: "phone"},{id:2,uId:2,text:"nick",category: "life"},{id:3,uId:3,text:"samsung",category: "phone"}],
user:[{id:1,name: "Joe"},{id:2,name: "red"},{id:3,name: "blue"}]}]

let final = testList.map(v => {
  let mapper = new Set(v.content.filter(({
    category
  }) => category === "phone").map(({
    id
  }) => id))
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(v).map(([key, value]) => {
    value = value.filter(({
      id
    }) => mapper.has(id))
    return [key, value]
  }).filter(([_, value]) => value))
})

console.log(final)
```

---

> if `Object.fromEntries` is not supported

```js
var testList = [{content:[{id:1,uId:1,text:"apple", category: "phone"},{id:2,uId:2,text:"nick",category: "life"},{id:3,uId:3,text:"samsung",category: "phone"}],
user:[{id:1,name: "Joe"},{id:2,name: "red"},{id:3,name: "blue"}]}]

let final = testList.map(v => {
  let mapper = new Set(v.content.filter(({
    category
  }) => category === "phone").map(({
    id
  }) => id))
  return Object.entries(v).map(([key, value]) => {
    value = value.filter(({
      id
    }) => mapper.has(id))
    return [key, value]
  }).filter(([_, value]) => value).reduce((op,[k,v])=>{
    op[k] = v
    return op
  },{})
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I believe the `uId` (user id) is the foreign key which links the user to the phone, whereas `id` is the id for each entry and possibly not shared, but that's a small thing for the OP to confirm. Nice approach though

Comment: @NickParsons thanks mate :) not sure both seemed similar so i used `id` as both of the structures hold the same property this is what my guess was, anyways can be changed to `uId` easily just by utilizing `uId` instead of `id` while building set

Comment: I'm sorry I don't support 'object.fromentries'

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao can be easily replaced by `reduce` or any other method let me update that too

Comment: @CodeManiac I'm not very familiar with `reduce`,Could you please update it?

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you very much for your help. If possible, I would also like to learn the usage of `reduce`

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao [`Reduce MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) Here a place to start reading this is a good resource you can start with it

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you very much. Could you please update it? I'd like to try

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao what do you mean by update ? second snippet uses the reduce. and you can read more on the link i provided in above comment

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the indices first and then filter by wanted indices.

```js
var testList = [{ content:[{ id: 1, uId: 1, text: "apple", category: "phone" }, { id: 2, uId: 2, text: "nick", category: "life" }, { id: 3, uId: 3, text: "samsung", category: "phone" }], user:[{ id: 1, name: "Joe" }, { id: 2, name: "red" }, { id: 3, name: "blue" }] }],
    result = testList.map(o => {
        var indices = [...o.content.keys()].filter(i => o.content[i].category === 'phone');
        return Object.assign({}, ...['content', 'user'].map(k => ({ [k]: o[k].filter((_, i) => indices.includes(i)) })));
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the content to find the category items and after filter the users in the list intens found.

```js
var list = [
  {
    content:[
      {id:1,uId:1,text:"apple", category: "phone"},
      {id:2,uId:2,text:"nick",category: "life"},
      {id:3,uId:3,text:"samsung",category: "phone"}
    ],
    user:[
      {id:1,name: "Joe"},
      {id:2,name: "red"},
      {id:3,name: "blue"}
    ]
  }
];

const result = list.map(items => {
  const content = items.content.filter(c => c.category === 'phone');
  const users = items.user.filter(u => content.find(c => u.id === c.id));
  
  return {
    content: content,
    user: users,
  }
});
                         
 
console.log(result);
```